# Change default screenshot format for iPhone 6 Plus running iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, screen-capture

I would like to change the format of a screenshot from .png to .tiff. Is this possible? Moreover, is it possible to write a script or some equivalent that can automate screenshots on any apple mobile device i.e. iPhone and/or iPad?

Comment: png is lossless anyway, so why would you really need tif?

Comment: I don't want any compression on the files for archival and editing purposes. png format also supports lossy compression as well I take it? Am I simply to take Apple in full faith that they use lossless compression?

Answer (score 3):

It is currently not possible to change the format of screenshots from PNG, however there are many ways to change image using a PC.

As for your second question, this is only possible by jailbreaking your iOS device and installing SSCapture.

Comment: Do you know of some convenient clever workaround I can use to change the default format, perhaps via jailbreaking one of my older devices with expired warranty?

Comment: You could try and install ImageMagick to help you convert the png into a tiff file.